# How can I secure images in S3 buckets with Auth0 and a React front-end

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, auth0

Let's say that I have an S3 bucket with a few images in it. These images are accessible through an HTTP URL like any other S3 resource. For example, one image is located at `http://www.awss3.com/s3_bucket_name/the_image.png`.

---

Here is my question:

If I am creating a React front-end application that displays images using the `<img>` tag, how can I use Auth0 to secure the S3 bucket images so that they are only displayed or accessible to users that are authenticated and authorized? For example, I only want this image to show up on the React page if the user has been authenticated and authorized: `<img src="http://www.awss3.com/s3_bucket_name/the_image.png" />`.

Let's assume that the user is logged in and the React front-end has a good Auth0 JWT available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [Serving Private Content with Signed URLs and Signed Cookies - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html):

> **You Can Serve Private Content with Signed URLs and Signed Cookies**
>
> Many companies that distribute content over the internet want to restrict access to documents, business data, media streams, or content that is intended for selected users, for example, users who have paid a fee. To securely serve this private content by using CloudFront, you can do the following:
>
> - Require that your users access your private content by using special CloudFront signed URLs or signed cookies.
> - Require that your users access your content by using CloudFront URLs, not URLs that access content directly on the origin server (for example, Amazon S3 or a private HTTP server). Requiring CloudFront URLs isn't necessary, but we recommend it to prevent users from bypassing the restrictions that you specify in signed URLs or signed cookies.

From [Overview of Serving Private Content - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-overview.html):

> You can control user access to your private content in two ways:
>
> - Restrict access to files in CloudFront edge caches
> - Restrict access to files in your origin by doing one of the following:
>
>   - Set up an origin access identity (OAI) for your Amazon S3 bucket (unless you've configured it as a website endpoint)
>   - Configure custom headers for a private HTTP server or an Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website endpoint
>
> **Restricting Access to Files in Amazon S3 Buckets**
>
> You can optionally secure the content in your Amazon S3 bucket so that users can access it through CloudFront but cannot access it directly by using Amazon S3 URLs. This prevents someone from bypassing CloudFront and using the Amazon S3 URL to get content that you want to restrict access to. This step isn't required to use signed URLs, but we recommend it. Be aware that this option is only available if you have not set up your Amazon S3 bucket as a website endpoint.
>
> To require that users access your content through CloudFront URLs, you do the following tasks:
>
> - Create a special CloudFront user called an origin access identity.
> - Give the origin access identity permission to read the files in your bucket.
> - Remove permission for anyone else to use Amazon S3 URLs to read the files.

For more information, see: [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Answer (score 2):

To provide application users with access to objects in Amazon S3:

- Keep the objects as **private**
- Users **authenticate** to your application
- When a user wants access to a private object, your application can generate a **pre-signed URL**, which is a time-limited link to an object
- Users can **access the object directly from Amazon S3** (eg via an `<img>` tag) but once the URL expires, it no longer provides access

See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: @Nirmal How will a pre-signed URL impact performance? It only takes a couple of lines of code to generate (which does not involve a call to AWS). See: [`getSignedUrl()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)

Comment: @Nirmal - I'm curious as well, how can a pre-signed URL impact performance?

Comment: Signed url and Pre-Signed url has some differences. Check below links https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html   and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html  We have to generated signed url before serving the content that require extra call.

Comment: The question is only referring to Amazon S3, not Amazon CloudFront.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you gave reference for PreSigned url in your answer and that require an extra call which will can be valid (for max 6/36/168 hrs depends on how you created  )

Comment: A "call" to generate a pre-signed URL is not a call to AWS. It's a local function that calculates the signature using a hash function. Here's a way to try it... disconnect your computer from the Internet, then generate the pre-signed URL. It still works. So, it doesn't have a performance impact.

Comment: What to do if user wants to delete that file?

Comment: @ElaineChen A desire to change or delete the file would be the responsibility of the application to implement. The application has the necessary permissions to delete the object. You would need to code the necessary logic into the application. End-users _cannot_ delete objects through pre-signed URLs.